# Why is the required attribute in javascript form validation only works for one button in my form?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form class="address-form" id="form" name="addressForm">
            <div class="form-container">
                <div class="form-input abc">
                    <label>Full name</label>
                    <input class="form-input-name" type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Enter your full name" maxlength="50" value="{{ customer.name }}" required>
                    <div class="input-error hidden" id="input-error-name">Please enter your name</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-input abc">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input class="form-input-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" maxlength="50" value="{{ customer.email }}" required>
                    <div class="input-error hidden" id="input-error-email">Please enter your email</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-input abc">
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input class="form-input-city" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter your city" maxlength="50" required>
                    <div class="input-error hidden" id="input-error-city">Please enter your city</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-input abc">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <textarea name="address" class="form-input-address" placeholder="For example: 92 Nguyen Huu Canh street" required></textarea>
                    <div class="input-error hidden" id="input-error-address">Please enter your address</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check abc">
                    <label></label>
                    <input class="tickbox" type="checkbox" onclick="checkTickbox()" id="flexCheckDefault" style="cursor: pointer" name="default">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: 500; font-size: 12px">
                      Set as default address
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-container abc">
                    <label></label>
                    <div class="button-group">
                        <button class="cancel-button btn btn-light" id="cancel" formnovalidate>Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="create-update-button btn btn-primary" id="create-update">Ship to this address</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I don't know why my code is acting weird, the required attribute works on the cancel button, but doesn't validate the form when I pressed the submit button. However, the submit button actually works when I commented out the cancel button. I currently have an event listener for the submit button which will send the form's data via a POST request when clicked, I don't know if that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

By default button type is submit , since cancel button does not have type defined so it will work as submit . Add button type button to cancel button

```
<button type = 'button' class="cancel-button btn btn-light" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it and it doesn't validate on the cancel button anymore, but the submit button still doesn't validate the form

Answer (score 0):

the The required attribute only  works with types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, date pickers, number, checkbox, radio, and file. so you should specified the type in here :

```
<textarea name="address" class="form-input-address" placeholder="For example: 92 
       Nguyen Huu Canh street" required>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I don't know if that's true because the required attribute in textarea validation works perfectly fine when I commented out the cancel button, so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: here is the[ link ](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp#:~:text=The%20required%20attribute%20is%20a,checkbox%2C%20radio%2C%20and%20file.)if not it's js problem

Comment: I copied your form and it workes for me but the require works one by one in the html so if the first input is blank it would work only on it and show the msg there ..try filling them one by one and every time press button . you will see that the required works for them all .if you want to show errors or something use js

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem, I added an event listener for button clicked rather than the submit event